spring boot kafka listener consuming messages multiple times
I have a spring boot + kafka application, which consumes the messages from kafka, process and update DB. We have set "manual auto commit" and the max poll records as "500" and max poll interval is 1000ms and concurrency set as "100".
The problem we are facing is multiple threads from different(or even from same pod as I checked in logs) pods (currently we have 4 pods running) consuming the messages and end up inserting duplicate records in DB. Kafka partitions are 4.
Some of the solutions seen in the internet and tried are

Make the application idempotent - not possible in my application
Use same groupId - I have given same groupId as we have deployed same code base.
reduce the maxpoll records and increase the poll interval - This I have tried not dont  see much improvement.
partitions and pods should be same - we are maintaining the same.

Can someone please help, what is the best we can do ?. Is there any property in kafka or spring boot which will enable us to make the application to consume only once despite running multiple instances?

Are you using isolated level setting in the consumer? Are you able to provide logs with partition and offset of each such duplicate record mentioned?

It seems to be the issue of different values of "group.id" for all the consumers. If you have tried it then can you specify all the properties of kafka consumer that you have specified

@OneCricketeer and Deepanshu, The issue is resolved after we increase the max poll interval to default value (5 minutes). Initially we changed to around 500ms thinking it could increase the performance. But increase or decrease the max poll interval not impacting the performance, so reset to default value and no issues so far, will post here if any. Thanks for the reply.
